# How did they do this with SVG's, a static image, hotspots and javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

About half way down on the following site there is an image of a house with SVG animations and hotspots.

https://enphase.com/en-us/homeowners

I see all the individual elements but I don't understand how the they put it all together.  The elements are positioned using percentages to 5 decimal places.  I'm assuming they used some software to create the SVGs put more importantly, the layout.  Any idea what that software is?  There is now way they hand coded the layout and calculated the positioning.

Comment: Maybe they did it with a similar tool like this:
https://www.svgator.com/

i always did this by hand

Comment: SVGator would take care of the individual SVGs, but what about all the absolute positioning to the 5th decimal and such.  It is the layout that stumps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the same functionality using SVG [stroke-dasharray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) and [stroke-dashoffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dashoffset) attributes mainipulation with javascript animation timers, I usually use [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) to do this type of animation/SVG manipulation, but you can also do it purely in javascript, here is a [block example](http://bl.ocks.org/veltman/f1172731aa3c01fb5179536f9dea0a58) by `Noah Veltman` on [bl.ocks.org](https://bl.ocks.org/):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
    path {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #d3008c;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    #arrowhead {
      fill: #d3008c;
      stroke: none;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="960" height="500">
  <path d="M636.5,315c-0.4-18.7,1.9-27.9-5.3-35.9
   c-22.7-25-107.3-2.8-118.3,35.9c-7,24.4,20.6,37.2,16,71c-4,29.6-30.8,60.7-56.5,61.1c-30.8,0.4-32.9-43.8-81.7-70.2
   c-50.9-27.6-110.1-12.9-125.2-9.2c-66.1,16.4-82.2,56.9-109.2,47.3c-38-13.6-55.9-112.1-19.8-143.5c39-34,121.2,27.7,148.1-3.8
   c18-21.1,3.1-74.3-25.2-105.3c-31.1-34.1-70.1-32.4-105.3-76.3c-8.2-10.2-16.9-23.8-15.3-39.7c1.2-11.4,7.5-23.3,15.3-29
   c33.8-25,101.6,62.6,193.1,59.5c40.1-1.3,38.7-18.5,99.2-38.9c126.2-42.6,242.4-4.9,297.7,13c54.7,17.7,105.4,35,129.8,82.4
   c13,25.3,22.9,67.7,4.6,87c-11.6,12.3-25.1,5.1-46.6,20.6c-2.8,2-28.9,21.4-32.1,49.6c-3.1,27.4,18.7,35,29,70.2
   c8.8,30.1,8.5,77.8-18.3,99.2c-32.3,25.8-87,0.6-100-5.3c-69.6-32-67.2-88.4-73.3-109.2z"/>
    <defs>
      <path id="arrowhead" d="M7,0 L-7,-5 L-7,5 Z" />
    </defs>
</svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

  var path = document.querySelector("path"),
      totalLength = path.getTotalLength(),
      group = totalLength / 20,
      start;

  var arrowheads = d3.select("svg").selectAll("use")
    .data(d3.range(20).map(function(d){ return d * group + 50; }))
    .enter()
    .append("use")
      .attr("xlink:href", "#arrowhead");

  path.style.strokeDasharray = "50," + (group - 50);

  requestAnimationFrame(update);

  function update(t) {
    if (!start) {
      start = t;
    }

    var offset = -group * ((t - start) % 900) / 900;

    path.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;

    arrowheads.attr("transform",function(d){

      var l = d - offset;

      if (l < 0) {
        l = totalLength + l;
      } else if (l > totalLength) {
        l -= totalLength;
      }

      var p = pointAtLength(l);
      return "translate(" + p + ") rotate( " + angleAtLength(l) + ")";
    });

    requestAnimationFrame(update);
  }

  function pointAtLength(l) {

    var xy = path.getPointAtLength(l);
    return [xy.x, xy.y];

  }

  // Approximate tangent
  function angleAtLength(l) {

    var a = pointAtLength(Math.max(l - 0.01,0)), // this could be slightly negative
        b = pointAtLength(l + 0.01); // browsers cap at total length

    return Math.atan2(b[1] - a[1], b[0] - a[0]) * 180 / Math.PI;

  }

</script>
```

And this is how the `<path>` looks like without animations:

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #d3008c;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

#arrowhead {
  fill: #d3008c;
  stroke: none;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="960" height="500">
  <path d="M636.5,315c-0.4-18.7,1.9-27.9-5.3-35.9
   c-22.7-25-107.3-2.8-118.3,35.9c-7,24.4,20.6,37.2,16,71c-4,29.6-30.8,60.7-56.5,61.1c-30.8,0.4-32.9-43.8-81.7-70.2
   c-50.9-27.6-110.1-12.9-125.2-9.2c-66.1,16.4-82.2,56.9-109.2,47.3c-38-13.6-55.9-112.1-19.8-143.5c39-34,121.2,27.7,148.1-3.8
   c18-21.1,3.1-74.3-25.2-105.3c-31.1-34.1-70.1-32.4-105.3-76.3c-8.2-10.2-16.9-23.8-15.3-39.7c1.2-11.4,7.5-23.3,15.3-29
   c33.8-25,101.6,62.6,193.1,59.5c40.1-1.3,38.7-18.5,99.2-38.9c126.2-42.6,242.4-4.9,297.7,13c54.7,17.7,105.4,35,129.8,82.4
   c13,25.3,22.9,67.7,4.6,87c-11.6,12.3-25.1,5.1-46.6,20.6c-2.8,2-28.9,21.4-32.1,49.6c-3.1,27.4,18.7,35,29,70.2
   c8.8,30.1,8.5,77.8-18.3,99.2c-32.3,25.8-87,0.6-100-5.3c-69.6-32-67.2-88.4-73.3-109.2z"/>
    <defs>
      <path id="arrowhead" d="M7,0 L-7,-5 L-7,5 Z" />
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Any ideas how they determined all the absolute positioning of the individual SVGs and such?  Not sure how they got that precise unless they were using some layout tool and then exported things.

Comment: No, for such a thing, they made the whole SVG (including the path) using vector graphics editor such as [adobe illustrator](https://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator.html) then export it for web, and the animation was made using javascript since SVG is XML file somehow similar to HTML.

Comment: its not too hard, I developed much harder layout than this, one of them was airport surface visualization.

Comment: So Illustrator exports all the individual elements with associated HTML.  The example has hotspots for the flashing buttons, a background image for the house, a bunch of CSS to position the individual SVG's that dynamically get moved as the browser window sizes down.

Comment: doesn't have to be Illustrator, Illustrator was an example, there is a lot of tools out there allow you to work on any type of graphics and export it later, e.g Autocade is one of them, but usually adobe products are the best for exporting SVG to HTML5 for animation.

Comment: I don't think I'm asking the correct question.  Beyond the graphical animated elements, Illustrator exports all the HTML including the CSS to make this example happen? There is a lot of code used in this example for the hotspots that trigger the hover graphics for example.  I haven't said it yet, but thanks for walking me through this.

Comment: ok, you mean if there is a tool used to create such an app (HTML5 with animation and effects)? if yes, then I got what you are asking for, there are a lot of tools can be used, one of them is [Adobe_Animate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Animate) this app allow you to create HTML5 interactive apps and even games , before it was [Adobe-edge-animate](https://www.adobe.com/nz/products/edge-animate.html), these apps meant to replace Adobe Flash with HTML5 using SVG graphics.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  I figured some app had to be doing something extensive because it would be difficult/impossible to create the layout with absolute positioned to 5 decimals by hand. Thanks!